# C - How can I free dynamically allocated memory?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

Have a look at this piece of codes, it's part of a linked list.

```
int main()

{
    List* head1 = NULL;

    insertFront(&head1, 1);
    insertFront(&head1, 2);

    print(head1);

    free(head1);

    return 0;
}
```

another function is:

```
void insertFront(List** head, int value)

{
    List* node = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    node->data = value;
    node->next = NULL;

    node->next = *head;
    *head = node;

   //free(node); essentially I am not freeing node
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is my code going to cause memory leak problem?
2. Should I need to free the allocated memory (dynamically) for node (Which is inside a function)?
3. If I free head1, will the memory allocated for node also be freed? If yes, then how?

Comment: You do not need the cast in front of `malloc`

Comment: @EdHeal yes, thanks I have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a memory leak because you are only freeing the first node in the list.  You don't want to `free` in the `insertNode` function otherwise you're immediately throwing away memory you just allocated.

At the end of your program, you need to traverse the list and `free` each element.

```
while (head1) {
    List *temp = head1;
    head1 = head1->next;
    free(temp);
}
```